# Schengen Business Visa with my wife

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

Hello I will apply schengen business visa, and my company will sponsor it. They will provide all cost and invitation letter. However, I want my wife to accompany me. What type of schengen visa do i need to apply for her? And do we need to apply at the same time?

Comment: Schengen makes no difference between a business visa and a tourism visa. The only difference is in the explanation one provides.

Comment: so I can apply both for me and my wife at the same time?

Comment: Yes. You must take care to keep your papers organized. *You* travel for business, with a little bit of tourism (that's permitted). *She* travels for tourism only. Your company will pay the business trip, presumably you will pay for the tourism. They will want to know if you can afford it. You should both make it plausible that you'll leave the Schengen area again.

Comment: we have US visa, will it be an advantage?

Comment: We cannot give odds. The reasons why the US gave you a visa will be useful in Schengen, too. Steady financial situation, ties to the homeland, etc.